# Facebook Login API not sending email id

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am integrating facebook login in my website for which I have created a app on facebook and implement the login code by using [Facebook Login Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Even I have added a scope for email id still I am not getting email id of any user in response. Please see below SG:

[image]
[image]

Why I am not getting email id in response even after it is asking permission to user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you forget to ask for the email field in the API call: `/me?fields=name,email`

...or with the JS SDK:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I am asking that email scope that is why you can see the screenshot 1 it is asking user for email permission

Comment: scope is just for permissions in the login popup. you still have to use the fields parameter to get the email. just try it in your api call.